# how to use a promoted class in PyQt5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

in principal I reopen my question some days ago:

**where-do-i-write-the-class-for-a-single-promoted-qwidget-from-qt-designer**

The solution works, but I run into 2 more questions

if I want to change the text in the class neuLabel, how do i adress the class out of main program?

Additional information for minimal example as required:

I have a qt designer main window, named testpromote.ui. It contains only one label. Text is "MyLabel", the name is neuLabel and it is promoted as neulabel.

I need 2 .py files in one directory.
First the main **testpromote.py**

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *  #QPainter
import neulabel



CURRENT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

uifile_1 = os.path.join(CURRENT_DIR, "testpromote.ui")
form_1, base_1 = uic.loadUiType(uifile_1)

class myApp(base_1, form_1):
    def __init__(self):
        super(base_1,self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        # ??????????????
        #neuLabel.setText(neuLabel,"from main")
        # ??????????????

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = myApp()   #Dialog()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

2nd file is **neulabel.py**

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *  #QPainter


class neuLabel(QLabel):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.setText("from code")

        print("the new pixmap?", self.text())
```

My aim is to change the text of the label out of the main program testpromote.py

I do not understand, how to import the neulabel.py, so that i could change the text of the label.I tried it with "neuLabel.setText(neuLabel,"from main")", but this doesn't work. I tried it with other code too, but not succesfully. (This is marked within the # ????????? lines)

To see, if the text in the label changes, I added in neulabel.py the

self.setText() statement, but the text does not change in the window.

(i hope, it is clearer now)

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: share the testpromote.ui

Comment: If you really tried `neuLabel.setText(neuLabel, "from main")` it will never work, since `neuLabel` is a class. You've to use the `setText` method of the object instance. If its object name was `promotedLabel` in the Designer, just use `self.promotedLabel.setText("from main")` after `setupUi`.